# Whats your favorite Reverse Sound

Tags: sound-design

i think one of the simple sound process is reverse sound and smtimes the result is very interesting
my favorite:
Glass crash,
Explosion,
Dialogue,,
Musical Note,
Cymbal Hit,
Church Bell,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reverse reverbed screams. Reversed glass crashes.

Answer (score 4):

Reversing whispered speech is always a favourite of mine, especially when creating 'evil' or 'creepy' ambiences. =)

Comment: Yeah, and I think now it is already such a cliche.

Comment: @Conant  Hmm, I guess so, but it really depends on how it's used. Reverse breath noises and such are extremely cliche, and are starting to sound a bit 'cheap'. But if you have a really good voice actor and a decent script you can still come up with some spine-tingling results!

Comment: good stuff to convolve too eg with wind

Answer (score 4):

Anything. EVERYTHING is better reversed. But, gun to head, reverse piano or harp gliss.

Answer (score 2):

When cutting car chases, reversing an accel away from the mic is a great substitute for a fast decel when you can't find a naturally recorded one.

Answer (score 2):

I really, really, really like recording sounds performed to be reversed i.e. conceive of the shape of the sound you want, reverse it in your mind, perform it that way, then record it & reverse

A simple example: I made a weird sting by used some drum brushes on the front of a metal gas heater to start gradually from nothing & build to very active friction... & ended suddenly by giving the heater a massive hit.... Reversed it ramps from the decay of that big hit into a loud backwards burst with a long backwards decay of the reversed brush movement

Answer (score 0):

Reversed acoustic guitar or piano is the best! Clean and reverberant recordings work well. This kind of thing is good for non-diagetic textural sound design or music composition.

Answer (score 0):

speaking backwards - i.e. speaking backwards then reversing so it goes forwards if you get my drift :)

Answer (score 0):

Bell tolls, metal tubular wind chimes.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely piano.